# ExpressionEngine API - Adding a category

Tags: php

I am wondering if it's possible to dynamically create a category using the Expression Engine API?

To explain my issue a little, I'm reading a 3rd party SOAP API which returns me a list of categories which could change so I can't really pre-create my categories in EE. Within each of those categories are some articles.

Now I need to insert these articles into Expression Engine through the API which is fine but wanted to "tag" these articles based on their original categories.

Failing that the only way I can think to keep track of the article's original category is to make sure a channel exists for each category I find in the API, then insert into that channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into something like [Datagrab](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/products/details/datagrab) or [Importer](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/importer/) combined with, say, a nightly/hourly CRON job. It will automatically read the 3rd party service's XML and import stuff according to an import profile you create in the add-on which maps XML nodes to EE fields or categories.

Comment: Thanks James, these certainly look like they take care of a lot of the flaws with the official API that make it kind of hard to do this manually. Do you have any experience with either of the addons? I think I will run with Importer even though it is more expensive.

Comment: I've used Datagrab but not Importer. It's pretty easy to use. They can both handle cron jobs.